# Android XML Reading Problem

Tags: android, xml, file, parsing, mobile

```
public String parseCheck(File file) throws XPathExpressionException, SAXException, IOException
{

    Document doc=builder.parse(file);
    ....
```

I want to read an xml file but how do I pass the file when it is present in /res/xml/ folder. I couldn't find any way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way you will be able to get access to a File for something that is compiled into the resources.

If you are happy to work with an InputStream you could place your XML file into the assets folder instead and do something like the following:

```
InputStream xmlStream = getAssets().open("myfile.xml");
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the XML file to read

```
<maintag>
<item>
<name>AndroidPeople</name>
<website category="android">www.androidpeople.com</website>
</item>
<item>
<name>iPhoneAppDeveloper</name>
<website category="iPhone">www.iphone-app-developer.com</website>
</item>
</maintag>
```

*XMLParsingExample.java*

```
your package name
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class XMLParsingExample extends Activity {

/** Create Object For SiteList Class */
SitesList sitesList = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

/** Create a new layout to display the view */
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(1);

/** Create a new textview array to display the results */
TextView name[];
TextView website[];
TextView category[];

try {

/** Handling XML */
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

/** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
URL sourceUrl = new URL(
"http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml");

/** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
}

/** Get result from MyXMLHandler SitlesList Object */
sitesList = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

/** Assign textview array lenght by arraylist size */
name = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
website = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];
category = new TextView[sitesList.getName().size()];

/** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
for (int i = 0; i < sitesList.getName().size(); i++) {
name[i] = new TextView(this);
name[i].setText("Name = "+sitesList.getName().get(i));
website[i] = new TextView(this);
website[i].setText("Website = "+sitesList.getWebsite().get(i));
category[i] = new TextView(this);
category[i].setText("Website Category = "+sitesList.getCategory().get(i));

layout.addView(name[i]);
layout.addView(website[i]);
layout.addView(category[i]);
}

/** Set the layout view to display */
setContentView(layout);

}
}
```

*MyXMLHandler.java*

```
 your package name
    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

    public class MyXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    Boolean currentElement = false;
    String currentValue = null;
    public static SitesList sitesList = null;

    public static SitesList getSitesList() {
    return sitesList;
    }

    public static void setSitesList(SitesList sitesList) {
    MyXMLHandler.sitesList = sitesList;
    }

    /** Called when tag starts ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
    * -- <name> )*/
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
    Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currentElement = true;

    if (localName.equals("maintag"))
    {
    /** Start */
    sitesList = new SitesList();
    } else if (localName.equals("website")) {
    /** Get attribute value */
    String attr = attributes.getValue("category");
    sitesList.setCategory(attr);
    }

    }

    /** Called when tag closing ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
    * -- </name> )*/
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
    throws SAXException {

    currentElement = false;

    /** set value */
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("name"))
    sitesList.setName(currentValue);
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("website"))
    sitesList.setWebsite(currentValue);

    }

    /** Called to get tag characters ( ex:- <name>AndroidPeople</name>
    * -- to get AndroidPeople Character ) */
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
    throws SAXException {

    if (currentElement) {
    currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
    currentElement = false;
    }

    }

    }
```

*SitesList.java*

```
your package name
import java.util.ArrayList;

/** Contains getter and setter method for varialbles */
public class SitesList {

/** Variables */
private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> website = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> category = new ArrayList<String>();

/** In Setter method default it will return arraylist
* change that to add */

public ArrayList<String> getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name.add(name);
}

public ArrayList<String> getWebsite() {
return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
this.website.add(website);
}

public ArrayList<String> getCategory() {
return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
this.category.add(category);
}
    }
```

the above is perfect working code.. you can download it from [XMLParsing.zip](http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/XMLParsing.zip) hope this useful for you thanks Pragna